# return the total number of neighbors by using pysal's weights object

Tags: pysal

I construct a weights object:

```
import pysal as ps
neighbors = {0: [3, 1], 1: [0, 2, 2], 2: [1, 2], 3: [0, 1, 1]}
weights = {0: [1, 1], 1: [1, 1, 1], 2: [1, 1], 3: [1, 1, 1]}
w = ps.W(neighbors, weights)
```

Weights object in `pysal` has a neighbors attribute like the following:

```
w.neighbors
```

It will returns a dict: `{0: [3, 1], 1: [0, 2, 2], 2: [1, 2], 3: [0, 1, 1]}`.

I've checked pysal's [api](https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/weights/weights.html) and find lots of methods and attribute to return something about the number of neighbors but not the total number of all neighbors.

For the above `w`, I want it to return something like: `{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3}`. Instead of looping over the dict like:

```
n_nbrs = dict()
for key, value in w.neighbors.items():
    n_nbrs[key] = len(value)
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `w.cardinalities`. It will return exactly what are you looking for - `{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3}`.

PySAL is currently changing its structure, so the `weights` module is now part of `libpysal` package and its [documentation](https://libpysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/libpysal.weights.W.html#libpysal.weights.W) is explaining it, unlike the one you are referring to.